# Publish from Visual Studio to website causes "access denied"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2000

I published a website using VS2005 to Win2k Server.  No errors were generated.
When I visit the page, I see this error:

Failed to start monitoring changes to 'E:\path\to\bin' because access is denied.

I logged in to the box with an Administrator account - and the folder won't let me change permissions or even view the files!  It says "access denied".

I'm a little stumped because this error is preventing the application from running.

Any suggestions?

Update:  When I right-click on the folder and choose "properties" - the security tab doesn't even show up - I can't get to this folder with any account on the box.  I'm really stumped (and a bit worried)

Update2: Tried to take ownership through the parent folder - access denied.  Tried to use the Security Policy editor and reset NTFS permissions - "The data is invalid" error. What in the world did Visual Studio screw up - and why in the world is Win2k preventing all access to these folders?!

Update3: I created a new folder on the server and changed the location of the .NET application's virtual directory so I can at least get it back up and running.  I'm still stuck with this rogue folder that I can't do anything with.

Comment: Have you been able to run a .net 2.0 web application on this server before?

Comment: The symptoms you are describing sound to me suspiciously like a virus infection. If possible, I suggest pulling the drive(s) and adding it/them to a known clean machine for scanning. Failing that scan from a live cd, such as Bart PE with ClamWin and up to date databases.

Comment: The server is currently running .Net 2.0 apps, yes.

I haven't had a chance to pull the drive - so I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Can use CACLS to see who has access to the folder?

For e.g.

> CACLS C:\FOLDERNAME

If yes then can you reset the user's password and runas that user to change permissions on the folder? For e.g.:

> runas /user:USERNAME "CACLS C:\FOLDERNAME\ /T /E /G EVERYONE:F"

Comment: access denied :(